# Bigquery DML operation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to execute 5 concurrent update queries on a single partitioned table. Out 0f 5 , 3 are from same partition and 2 are from different. While executing I expected one of the 3 queries will remain in pending state (2 running + 1 pending) and the other 2 will be in running state as they belong to different partition. But I observed 2 queries from same partition in  running state and rest 3 are in pending.

Is it like 2 queries at the same time can be in running state and the rest will be in pending state(queued) if all belongs to the same table irrespective of partition ?

Answer (score 0):

All informations about updating partitioned table data using DML can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/using-dml-with-partitioned-tables).

Additionally, take a look for the [limitations and concurrent jobs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#known_issues) in DML. If you submit one or more mutating DML statements on a table while other mutating DML jobs on it are still running (or pending), BigQuery will run them concurrently, up to a fixed number of concurrent mutating DML statements. If you reach the concurrency limit, BigQuery automatically queues any additional mutating DML jobs in a PENDING state.

DML has some statement conflicts:

> Concurrently running mutating DML statements on a table might fail due
> to conflicts in the changes they make. BigQuery retries these
> failures.
>
> An INSERT DML statement that inserts rows to a table doesn't conflict
> with any other concurrently running DML statement.
>
> MERGE DML statements that contain only an INSERT clause with no UPDATE
> or DELETE clauses don't conflict with any other concurrently running
> DML statement.
>
> MERGE DML statements with UPDATE or DELETE clauses don't conflict with
> any other concurrently running DML statement as long the MERGE
> statement does not lead to update or deletion of existing rows.